# Role create command is not responding

Tags: discord.py

My command doesnt seem to be responding to the command. Also do I use hexadecimal value or something else?

````py
  @commands.command()
  async def rolecreate(self, ctx, rolename, rolecolour):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_role(name=f"{rolename}", colour=discord.Colour(rolecolour))
    await ctx.send(f"{rolename} role with the colour {rolecolour} has been created")```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need an `int` but you're passing a `str`, specify the `Colour` class in your `rolecolour` parameter:

```py
@commands.command()
async def rolecreate(self, ctx, rolecolour: discord.Colour, *, rolename):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_role(name=f"{rolename}", colour=rolecolour)
    await ctx.send(f"{rolename} role with the colour {rolecolour} has been created")
```